# How to get data from another table with ListView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'm sure this is a common thing, but searching came up with nothing. Perhaps I'm asking it wrong but...

I have a `ListView` that displays data from a `Message` table (ex: `MessageList.DataSource = GetAllMessages()`). Inside this table is foreign key `ImageID` that belongs to table `Image`. `Image` has a `Path` column that I need to attach to my `DataSource` before I call `DataBind()` to my list. Is there a way to attach `Path` to my list of all messages while making sure that everything lines up based on `ImageID`?

In other words, I am displaying a list of messages that contain pictures and I need to know the path of the image so I may show it. I want to set the `ImageUrl` property of the `asp:ImageButton` within my `ListView` to `'<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Path") %>'`, but no "Path" column exists in `Message` *before* the data bind. How do I make sure the `Eval` function has a `Path` column to bind to? I'd appreciate any direction, thanks for reading.

**EDIT** - Here's some code to help better explain how everything is set up

Here's my code to get all messages

```
    public static List<Message> GetAll()
    {
        List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();

        try
        {
            command = GetCommand("SelectAllMessages");
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                messages.Add(PopulateMessage(reader));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                conn.Close();
        }

        return messages;
    }
```

And here I display them in my ListView

```
    MessageList.DataSource = Message.GetAll(); // This is where I need to join
    MessageList.DataBind();
```

Surely there's a way to join `Message.GetAll()` and `Image.GetAll()` based on `ImageID`, and only add the `Path` column to `Message.GetAll()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution for anyone interested:

```
        // Init
        List<Message> msgs = CurrentUser.DisplayedMessages;
        List<HooliganDB.Image> imgs = HooliganDB.Image.GetAll();

        if (MessageList.Items.Count < CurrentUser.DisplayedMessages.Count)
        {
            // New messages found, rebind data
            var resultTable = from m in msgs
                              join i in imgs
                              on m.ImageID equals i.ImageID
                              select new
                              {
                                  MessageID = m.MessageID,
                                  TimeStamp = m.TimeStamp,
                                  Text = m.Text,
                                  RoomID = m.RoomID,
                                  ImageID = m.ImageID,
                                  aspUserID = m.aspUserID,
                                  Path = i.Path
                              };

            MessageList.DataSource = resultTable;
            MessageList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is include the `Image.ImageUrl` field on the list returned by `GetAllMessages()`. You can easily do this whether you're using SQL statement or Entity Framework LINQ to fetch the messages from DB.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. Do you have a preferred method or example code you'd like to share?

Comment: How do you fetch data from Messages table? Can you post the `GetAllMessages()` code?

Comment: Just did, check above. It's not really feasible for me to alter my `GetAll()` code, I really just need it to return messages only. I'd like to add the `Path` column outside of this code to keep `Messages` separate from `Images`